# Can a a priori unbounded infinite sum of analytic functions be analytic if it is equal another analytic function on a dense subset?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, analyticity

Let $B$ be a complex Banach space and $H,I_n:B\to\mathbb{C}$ be analytic functions such that on a dense subset 
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n = H.
$$
Does it hold that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n$ is an analytic function and hence
$$
 \sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n = H
$$on $B$?

If it is of any help, the dense subset is given by $\{  I_n\not=0$ for finitely many $n\geq0\}$.

To rephrase the question, do I need some sort of convergence of the infinite sum or do I have a chance since the equality holds on a dense subset?

Comment: Pointwise convergence of analytic functions on a dense set does not imply that they converge everywhere; this fails already on $\mathbb C$ (look up the article "Pointwise Limits of Analytic Functions" by Kenneth R. Davidson). So the additional information marked as "of any help" must be used here, if the solution is positive.

Comment: Of this I am aware. I thought that the fact that it cpnverges to an analytic function with domain the whole Banach space would make a difference. In that case the additional info wouldn't be needed.

Comment: Example 1 of the aforementioned article is a sequence of polynomials that converges to $0$ pointwise in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{0\}$ but not at $0$.

Comment: Ok in that case I guess it is time to give up and look for an argument for convergence. Write this as an "incomplete" counter example and I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I mean thank you for your help it is really appreciated!